# Compliance lung chest wall together

Tags: breathing

I do not understand compliance better why do the lung chestwall together system compliance is less than the individual compliance of lung and chest wall? shouldn’t it lie in middle? Please clear it.

Comment: Can you provide the source of this information?

Comment: Guyton and hall

Answer (score 0):

The compliance can be represented by the change in cavity volume caused by the change in unit transmural pressure. It is determined by the equation "compliance = ΔV/ΔP", which ΔV refers to the change of volume and ΔP is the change of transmural pressure. 
The transmural pressure mainly counteracts the effect of elastic resistance while enlarging the volume of lung/chestwall. So as we can see from the equation, compliance is inversely proportional to elastic resistance（which determines the pressure required for inhalation）. 
The total elastic resistance is the sum of (also is larger than) the individual elastic resistance of lung and chest wall. So according to the equation, the total compliance is less than the individual compliance of lung and chest wall.